# How to get autocompletion of css class to work in razor files without changing language type in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way to get autocompletion in VS Code for razor file css class and id attributes without having to change or switch language type?

I've already read posts here saying to either change the language mapping for .cshtml or .razor file, or installing extensions in VS Code to let one change the language mapping on the fly.

However, shouldn't VS Code be able to auto complete the css class or id attributes with list of available classes already linked to the file one is editing?

Already tried changing language type, but that changes the autocompletion for razor, and the code styling / highlighting changes. Looking to be able to get this accomplished without changing the editing environment.